# Tff: define the usage of Tensorflow.take() function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to mimic the federated learning implementation provided [here: Working with tff's clientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/working_with_client_data) in order to understand the code clearly.
I reached to this point where I need clarification in.

```
def preprocess_dataset(dataset):
  """Create batches of 5 examples, and limit to 3 batches."""

  def map_fn(input):
    return collections.OrderedDict(
        x=tf.reshape(input['pixels'], shape=(-1, 784)),
        y=tf.cast(tf.reshape(input['label'], shape=(-1, 1)), tf.int64),
    )

  return dataset.batch(5).map(
      map_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).take(5)
```

1. what does `dataset.batch(5)` refer to? are these batches are taking from the data to training and the 3 are for testing?
2. what does `.take(5)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
dataset.batch(5).map(
      map_fn, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).take(5)
```

You are first separating the samples in `dataset` into batches of 5. Afterwards, you are applying the `map_fn` function to each batch in `dataset` (5 samples at a time). Finally, with `dataset.take(5)`, you are returning 5 batches from `dataset`, where each batch has 5 samples.

In the example that you linked, `client_data` contains multiple `tf` datasets.

Comment: Well, thanks for your explanation, actually this comment in the beginning confused me ( """Create batches of 5 examples, and limit to 3 batches.""")